# C Preprocessor macros extension concatenation

Tags: c, macros

Suppose I would like to use the C Preprocessor to define a family of function, for which only a parameter type changes. Let's take for example allocation functions with parameters:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define type_vector(t)                                              \
t * t##vector(int32_t nl, int32_t nh)                               \
{                                                                   \
    t * v = NULL; /* malloc(...) */                                 \
    return v;                                                       \
}

type_vector(int8_t)
type_vector(int32_t)
type_vector(int64_t)

int main() {
    int32_t * p;
    p = int32_tvector(10, 12);
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine.

Now, suppose I would like to have shorter names for type in the function names: i8 instead of int8_t, i32 instead of int32_t, etc.
I do not want to add a second parameter to the macro function declaration, but instead have a single definition of "short" type names.
Basically, the first thing I wrote was:

```
#define sn_int8_t   i8
#define sn_int32_t  i32
#define sn_int64_t  i64

#define sn(t)          sn_##t

#define type_vector(t)                                              \
t * sn(t)##vector(int32_t nl, int32_t nh)                           \
{                                                                   \
    t * v = NULL; /* malloc(...) */                                 \
    return v;                                                       \
}

type_vector(int8_t)
type_vector(int32_t)
type_vector(int64_t)

int main() {
    int32_t * p;
    p = i32vector(10, 12);
    return 0;
}
```

However, this does not compile, giving the following error:

```
error: pasting ")" and "vector" does not give a valid preprocessing token
 t * sn(t)##vector(int32_t nl, int32_t nh)                           \
```

As far as I understood, the problem is due to having the ")" and the "#" side by side.
So I did the following:

```
#define sn_int8_t(f)   i8##f
#define sn_int32_t(f)  i32##f
#define sn_int64_t(f)  i64##f

#define sn2(t,f)       sn_##t(f)

#define type_vector(t)                                              \
t * sn2(t,vector)(int32_t nl, int32_t nh)                           \
{                                                                   \
    t * v = NULL; /* malloc(...) */                                 \
    return v;                                                       \
}

type_vector(int8_t)
type_vector(int32_t)
type_vector(int64_t)

int main() {
    int32_t * p;
    p = i32vector(10, 12);
    return 0;
}
```

And this works fine again.

Now, suppose I would like to add a prefix to the function name, e.g. "remote_".

Simply putting

```
#define type_vector(t)                                              \
t * remote_##sn2(t,vector)(int32_t nl, int32_t nh)                  \
{                                                                   \
    t * v = NULL; /* malloc(...) */                                 \
    return v;                                                       \
}
```

does not work, as sn2 is not expanded. So I tried this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define sn_int8_t(f)   i8##f
#define sn_int32_t(f)  i32##f
#define sn_int64_t(f)  i64##f

#define sn2(t,f)       sn_##t(f)

#define short_name(n,t,f) n##_##sn2(t,f)

#define remote_type_vector(t)                                       \
t * short_name(remote,t,vector)(int32_t nl, int32_t nh)             \
{                                                                   \
    t * v = NULL;                                                   \
    return v;                                                       \
}

remote_type_vector(int8_t)
remote_type_vector(int32_t)
remote_type_vector(int64_t)

int main() {
    int32_t * p;
    p = remote_i32vector(10, 12);
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, this does not work because the macro sn2 is not expanded, giving me declarations like:

```
int32_t * remote_sn2(int32_t,vector)
```

Is there any way to do that?

Note: I do not want to use C++ templates.

Comment: Some people are claiming this kind of magic is evil...

Comment: Using a _flexible array member_ would make thinks much simpler. About the rest: TL;DR. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I do not want to add a second parameter to the macro function declaration" - Why not? It's not that you invoke the macro very often. A second parameter would also allow you to use types with compound names (`char *`, `struct thing`) without a `typedef`.

Comment: In case you don't know, you can check preprocessor output with `gcc -E`, I guess all C compilers have an option to do that.

Comment: @EugeneSh. such dark arts have been banned since prehistory..  Practitioners of necromancy, witchcraft and C macros were routinely excommunicated or hung, drawn and quartered until at least the 18th century.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a unified solution that should work for all of your needs:

```
#define sn_int8_t(p,s)  p##i8##s
#define sn_int32_t(p,s) p##i32##s
#define sn_int64_t(p,s) p##i64##s

#define sn2(t,p,s)       sn_##t(p,s)

#define type_vector(t)                                              \
t * sn2(t,,vector)(int32_t nl, int32_t nh)                          \
{                                                                   \
    t * v = NULL; /* malloc(...) */                                 \
    return v;                                                       \
}

#define remote_type_vector(t)                                       \
t * sn2(t,remote,vector)(int32_t nl, int32_t nh)                    \
{                                                                   \
    t * v = NULL;                                                   \
    return v;                                                       \
}

type_vector(int8_t)
type_vector(int32_t)
type_vector(int64_t)

remote_type_vector(int8_t)
remote_type_vector(int32_t)
remote_type_vector(int64_t)
```